# error: variable myS is already defined in method main(String[]) String myS = myS + myString;

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char memoryArray[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
        int s = 1;
        int l = 3;
        String myS = "";
        for (int i = s; i < s + l; i++) {
            char tmp = memoryArray[i];
            String myString = Character.toString(tmp);
            String myS = myS + myString;
        }
    }
}
```

**hey so I tried doing everything, the gist of my code is to transform these characters into a string that you can add, now the original code is much more complicated but I gave an oversimplified code to find out why this error is happening, if someone can please explain why?**

Comment: Try removing this line of your code: `String myS = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the code as shown below

```
String myS = myS + myString;
```

To

```
myS = myS + myString;
```

you cannot declare variable with same name again in same method

Comment: Hello, Id genuinely like to apologize for my lack of braincells.

Comment: No worries it happens to all of us. If my answer helped you in resolving the issue. You may accept the answer